# snmptrap IPv6 destination not working

Tags: c, ipv6, net-snmp

I compile snmptrap as a "stand alone" application to run on an enbedded device.
Sending trap with IPv4 works like a charm, but when using an IPv6 address as the destination, the following is showing in the logs:

```
tdomain: tdomain_transport_full("snmptrap", "udp6:[fd64:3ef5:bb33::2]", 0, "[NIL]", "[NIL]")
tdomain: Found no domain from specifier "udp6"
```

I compiled my net-snmp (v5.7.2) libraries with

```
--enable-ipv6
--with-mib-modules="mibII/ipv6 host notification snmpv3mibs"
--with-transports="UDPIPv6 TCPIPv6"
```

And excecute the commandline app as:

```
snmptrap -v 1 -M ./mibs/ -c public 'udp6:[fd64:3ef5:bb33::2]' '1.2.
3.4.5.6' '172.16.11.144' 6 99 '55' 1.11.12.13.14.15  s "teststring"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for solving this?

Cheers,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Ipv6[**fd64:3ef5:bb33::2**] address is reachable, and you have successfully compiled the net-snmp library using --ipv6 enable,

After compilation you have instructed the snmpd to use both udp and udp6 protocol.

you can debug the [SNMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A2mPw7iSfY) protocol using Wireshark

Alternately you can try other client as well to send the IPv6 pdu to make sure your client is sending the right data.